# limit of the sequence $\{a_n\},$ where $a_n = \sin n/n$, as $n$ tends to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Using the definition of the limit of a sequence, how can I prove that the sequence $\{a_n\}$, where $a_n = \sin n/n$, as $n$ tends to $\infty$ has a limit of $0$?

Comment: Use the fact that $|\sin x| \le 1$ and do a comparison test.

Comment: Right, I can show it multiple ways via squeeze theorem and other methods, but I need to find some N such that for all n>N implies abs(Sn-s) < epsilon..... Not sure how to construct that N

Comment: You can show that $N=\lceil 1/\epsilon \rceil$ will work. I constructed that by finding the $N$ that works for the $1/n$ sequence that squeezes it.

Comment: Oh lord obviously, much appreciated @Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N$ is so large that $\dfrac 1 N<\varepsilon$, then for $n\ge N$ you have $\dfrac 1 n<\varepsilon$, and so $\left| \dfrac{\sin(n)} n \right| \le \left| \dfrac 1 n \right| <\varepsilon.$

Thus you need to choose an integer $N\ge \dfrac 1 \varepsilon$.